# Updating SQL server from Access front end

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is pretty new to me. I have an Access database that I was to upsize to a SQL server but to keep the Access front end to make this application available remotely. I have imported the data in the SQL database using SSMA which looks to be fine. However, when adding a new record to the Access frontend, the SQL server is not being updated. Am I missing something? I (think I) have linked the tables together but still not joy.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: Did you link your SQL server tables to Access?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is being stored, but not on the SQL Server then you almost certainly have not linked the tables correctly.
On your Access front end your starting point should be no tables (unless you have some tables deliberately reserved for the front end for some reason). You then link to the back end tables (because you said 'linked the tables together', I suspect you have copies of the tables still in your front end). 
During the linking process, Access will confirm if each link is established successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't imported the data from MS Access to SQL yet.

Check out the SQL Server Migration Assistant(SSMA) on how to do that.
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#Access.

First you need to migrate the data to SQL and then you link the data in SQL to MS-Access.
Once the tables are linked appropriately it will update in SQL as it is entered in Access.
To link the tables you need to first setup an ODBC and then in access select external data -> import -> more -> ODBC Database and select "Link to the data source by creating linked tables"

Check out this link: http://www.fontstuff.com/ebooks/free/fsLinkingToSQLServer.pdf to make sure you did it right.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.

Create a primary key for every table you want to edit in Access. set identity specification and Identity increment by 1 or ? (you can find this setting in column properties)  Make sure data type for primary key is int.

All boolean value fields should have constraint set to 0 and no null values.